# Grails: getting DOM string from g.render?

Tags: grails

I need to get the DOM string of a template. However, a highCharts chart is added to the template after it is loaded. When I use g.render, I do not get the chart in the resultant string. Basically, the javascript doesn't run. Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to get something rendered on the client (by javascript) on the server (before it is rendered)?

Comment: on the server. is there any way of doing this?

Comment: but the javascript needs to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If some kind of javascript has to run on the client, before the server is doing something else, you have to use ajax to make a callback from the client. See the [grails ajax docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#ajax) for code examples.